# Instax-api issue---Only prints small (400 x 400) jpgs not full resolution 600 x 800 images

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

Can anyone help with the following issue when using the python "instax-api", please?

I'm trying to create an open source camera for artists called Yarbus Cam (influenced by the work of Alfred Yarbus). The idea is to create a scanpath using eyetracking/gaze direction from the camera user and then overlay an image of this data onto a photograph they take. I'd like to print out the final image using a Fuji Instax SP-2.
To do this I'm exploring the instax-api found here:
https://pypi.org/project/instax-api/

I've installed it on a MacBook and a Raspberry Pi with varying results on both. Ultimately I would like to get it working on the Raspberry Pi as the camera will be based on this platform.

Here are my findings and issues:

***Running Instax-Api On MacBook Pro***

I can only print a small image, for example, 450pixels X 450 pixels at 72dpi, otherwise the API throws exceptions (full resolution for the printer should be 600 x 800 @ 320dpi as described here: https://domvarney.com/2016/11/07/instax-sp2-part-1/)

If I try to print full res, I get the following error:

```
self.myImage = pure_pil_alpha_to_color_v2(newImage, (255,255,255))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/instax/instaxImage.py", line 268, in pure_pil_alpha_to_color_v2
    background.paste(image, mask=image.split()[3])  # 3 is the alpha channel
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

I've played around with this code in instaxImage.py changing the number in the python list - weirdly if I set it to [2](https://domvarney.com/2016/11/07/instax-sp2-part-1/) instead of [3]

```
background.paste(image, mask=image.split()[2])
```

the picture will print full size!! But it is missing a layer so it looks weirdly solarised and faded... Obviously changing the [2](https://domvarney.com/2016/11/07/instax-sp2-part-1/) back to [3] stops the code from working again. I know it can print full size, but how can I overcome the tuple out of range error?

If the image is an RGB image coming from Photoshop, how could it have values out of range of the 0 to 255 expected in the tuple? Is the code expecting an image with an Alpha channel so RGB + A (to give the 0,1,2,3 positions in the Python list?) What can I do to get it to work and print full size with all of the colours, etc?

It looks like the code is set up to rotate the image, rescale it, etc... This is maybe too much for what I want - has anyone experimented with a barebones version of this that just prints a full-size image?

***Running Instax-API On RASPBERRY PI***

With the Raspberry Pi 2 Model 2 V1.1, I am connected to the printer by wifi and my WLAN is configured.

I've enabled DHCP:

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces

iface wlan0 inet dhcp
```

However, when I try to send a print across to the instax from the command line:

```
sudo instax-print /home/pi/image.jpg
```

I get the following

```
--- Instax Printer Python Client---

Connecting to Printer
```

Followed by this error:

> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/instax_api-0.6-py3.4.egg/instax/sp2.py", line 44 in connect
>   raise(ConnectionError(reply.data))
>   instax.exceptions.ConnectionError: [Errno 113] No route to host

It looks like the Pi can't connect to the printer. How can I resolve this issue or begin to approach a solution?

instax-api is definitely installed - when I type in the command line:

```
instax-print -h
```

I get the human-readable information for instax-print.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [This issue](https://github.com/jpwsutton/instax_api/issues/11) from the instax-api github repo seems to be related to the `IndexError` that you are getting.

Comment: Thanks Lauren - that totally sorted the issue out. For others who are experiencing this problem (and its not completely clear from the post here 
exactly what to do

Comment: Thanks @lauren-Van-Sloun https://stackoverflow.com/users/7680801/lauren-van-sloun - that totally sorted the issue. 
Here's what I did:
Go into the instax folder. For me it was found here:
'code' dm-shoes$ cd /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/instax

'code' dm-shoes-3:instax dm-shoes$ sudo nano instaxImage.py

then change the line of code in the file 'instaxImage.py' from

'code'background.paste(image, mask=image.split()[3]) # 3 is the alpha channel

to

'code'background.paste(image)

and it works!!

Comment: answering your own question is actively encouraged. As there is quite a lot of info in your previous comment, that may be a good option in this case.

Comment: OP, I think you meant to tag @SuperShoot instead of me. I simply edited your post. He is the one that gave you that link. :)

Comment: You're right Lauren! 
Thanks @SuperShoot for the link to the issue that resolved the first part of my question!!